# How to call multiple namespaced Modules in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I don't know how to call, multiple NamespacedHelpers with vuex, i tried this:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapActions, mapMutations } = createNamespacedHelpers(['payments', 'auth'])
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['registerBankData', 'updateBankData', 'getBankData'], ['login']),
    ...mapMutations(['setBankData']),
...
}
```

Also tried this:

```
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapActions, mapMutations } = createNamespacedHelpers('payments', 'auth')
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['registerBankData', 'updateBankData', 'getBankData', 'login']),
    ...mapMutations(['setBankData']),
...
}
```

but doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
import { mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      myMutation: 'myModule/myMutation',
    }),
    ...mapActions({
      myAction: 'myModule/myAction',
    }),
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it worked very well, is it the only way to do it?

Comment: There are other options in [official documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace), but I prefer this way because it's more simple.

Comment: Cool! Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this

```js
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const payments = createNamespacedHelpers('payments')
const auth = createNamespacedHelpers('auth')

methods: {
    ...payments.mapActions(['registerBankData', 'updateBankData', 'getBankData']),
    ...auth.mapActions(['authAction', 'login']),
    ...payments.mapMutations(['setBankData']),
...
}
```